# raid1 recovery: data recovery or raid rebuild, how to approach

Tags: command-line, data-recovery, raid

I am stuck while attempting to recover files from a former raid1 drive.
the 2e drive no longer exists and this dive has some memorable files on it i would prefer not to loose. So before messing with it any more then i already did and ask for advice.

what happened..
I changed over from a 2bay NAS (asustor as6102t) running a raid 1 system to a 4bay NAS (asustor 6604t) with the intention to back up essential data via a empty slot after i changed everything over (not the best choice ever i know, #1).

to make "sure" i wouldn't loose any data i entered the first drive into the new NAS and installed the new OS version.

Afterwards i learned that my new NAS has the option to install volume1 to SSD making the HD be able to go into hibernation, so i opted to go that way. Initially I though the SSD was only possible as cache drive.

so i booted the system with only the ssd thus creating the volume 1 on the SSD.
as drive 1 also had a volume 1 it was no longer recognized as such..
unfortunately at that point in time i put in BOTH old drives and ADM was probably still synchronizing the 2e drive to match the first one.

Then i realised that i could just save one of the two drives access the data after i created a volume2 on the other (second bad choice #2) and did just so, only to realise that ADM was still synchronising when i turned it off. (#3) and then i made the stupidest mistake ever, and i put the wrong (read the still "healthy") drive in to the nas instead of the drive that was still syncing when turning it off.. to create the new volume 2.

so now i am stuck with a drive that was turned off while probably still syncing the OS and info on that. The info of that actual data should still be fine. but i doubt that that is distinguishable.

Drive partitions:

```
/dev/sdb1  unknown    (no-mountpoint)  (no -label)    255.00 MiB  
/dev/sdb2  linux-raid /dev/md126,      AS6102T-30B9:0   2.00 GiB  
/dev/sdb3  linux-raid (no-mountpoint)  Matts-Ator:126   2.00 GiB   
/dev/sdb4  linux-raid (no-mountpoint)  AS6102T-30B9:1   7.27 TiB
```

What i tried so far:

- sudo -i
- root@pop-os:~# mdadm --assemble --scan

```
    mdadm: Merging with already-assembled /dev/md/AS6102T-30B9:1
    mdadm: failed to add /dev/sdd4 to /dev/md/AS6102T-30B9:1: Device or resource busy
    mdadm: /dev/md/AS6102T-30B9:1 assembled from -1 drives and 1 rebuilding - not enough to start the array.
    mdadm: Merging with already-assembled /dev/md/Matts-ATor:126
    mdadm: failed to add /dev/sdd3 to /dev/md/Matts-ATor:126: Device or resource busy
    mdadm: /dev/md/Matts-ATor:126 assembled from -1 drives and 1 rebuilding - not enough to start the array.
    mdadm: Found some drive for an array that is already active: /dev/md/AS6102T-30B9:0
    mdadm: giving up.
    mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
```

- mount -f ext4 /dev/sdb1 /mnt/oldhd (also /sdb2,3,4)

```
    mount: bad usage
```

- fdisk -l /dev/sdb

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 7.28 TiB, 8001563222016 bytes, 15628053168 sectors
Disk model:                 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 80C9725B-EB84-4899-8631-58B4881864EC

Device       Start         End     Sectors  Size Type

    /dev/sdb1     2048      524287      522240  255M Linux filesystem
    /dev/sdb2   524288     4718591     4194304    2G Linux RAID
    /dev/sdb3  4718592     8912895     4194304    2G Linux RAID
    /dev/sdb4  8912896 15628052479 15619139584  7.3T Linux RAID
```

- file -s /dev/sdb1

```
/dev/sdb1: data
```

- file -s /dev/sdb2

```
/dev/sdb2: Linux Software RAID version 1.2 (1) UUID=10a88f20:91ccdee6:ea11afed:9f053ae1 name=AS6102T-30B9:0 level=1 disks=4 !!!!
```

- file -s /dev/sdb3

```
Linux Software RAID version 1.2 (1) UUID= c0fb0c9:11ec2f32:dc9646a1:dc1d1f06 name=Matts-ATor:126 level=1 disks=2
```

- file -s /dev/sdb4

```
Linux Software RAID version 1.2 (1) UUID=807cfe7b:78c76a5f:  4f722d:fe27fe8b name=AS6102T-30B9:1 level=1 disks=2
```

- hexdump -C -n 32256 /dev/sdb

```
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 20  |............... |
000001c0  21 00 83 a2 02 20 00 08  00 00 00 f8 07 00 00 00  |!.... ..........|
000001d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001f0  02 00 ee 20 20 00 01 00  00 00 ff 07 00 00 55 aa  |...  .........U.|
00000200  45 46 49 20 50 41 52 54  00 00 01 00 5c 00 00 00  |EFI PART....\...|
00000210  c6 26 59 d2 00 00 00 00  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.&Y.............|
00000220  af 2a 81 a3 03 00 00 00  22 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.*......".......|
00000230  8e 2a 81 a3 03 00 00 00  5b 72 c9 80 84 eb 99 48  |.*......[r.....H|
00000240  86 31 58 b4 88 18 64 ec  02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.1X...d.........|
00000250  80 00 00 00 80 00 00 00  db d7 ad b0 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000260  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000400  af 3d c6 0f 83 84 72 47  8e 79 3d 69 d8 47 7d e4  |.=....rG.y=i.G}.|
00000410  04 7c 37 51 c8 32 a3 43  b3 b7 d9 36 e8 ad b9 54  |.|7Q.2.C...6...T|
00000420  00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00  ff ff 07 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000430  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000480  0f 88 9d a1 fc 05 3b 4d  a0 06 74 3f 0f 84 91 1e  |......;M..t?....|
00000490  9f 20 9f 97 c1 07 15 47  81 75 00 ed 80 c0 9f c6  |. .....G.u......|
000004a0  00 00 08 00 00 00 00 00  ff ff 47 00 00 00 00 00  |..........G.....|
000004b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000500  0f 88 9d a1 fc 05 3b 4d  a0 06 74 3f 0f 84 91 1e  |......;M..t?....|
00000510  c5 44 a7 a4 dc ec 3d 48  ae f9 8f 5a 66 c2 da cb  |.D....=H...Zf...|
00000520  00 00 48 00 00 00 00 00  ff ff 87 00 00 00 00 00  |..H.............|
00000530  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000580  0f 88 9d a1 fc 05 3b 4d  a0 06 74 3f 0f 84 91 1e  |......;M..t?....|
00000590  62 7d e4 a3 79 03 5f 4a  97 9e 9d 03 da a5 46 9d  |b}..y._J......F.|
000005a0  00 00 88 00 00 00 00 00  ff 27 81 a3 03 00 00 00  |.........'......|
000005b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00007e00
```

any thoughts on how to approach this further would be very much appreciated

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have since then tried data recovery with r linux.
scan went well, but unfortunately the *.scn file didn't wanna load properly.
Contacted the r-linux customer service who replied quick and informative.. but basically stating that i would need to do another scan.

not feeling like another +10hr scan i did again a search for options and this time i found this link.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72279/how-do-i-recover-files-from-a-single-degraded-mdadm-raid1-drive-not-enough-to

after a read through i found that:

- mdadm --examine /dev/sdb4
- losetup --find --show --read-only --offset $((262144*512)) /dev/sdb4
  /dev/loop0
- sudo mkdir /mnt/recovery
- sudo mount -o ro /dev/loop0 /mnt/recovery

Did the trick, Where:

- sbd4 is my data partition,
- 262144 my data offset found by mdadm --examine,
- /dev/loop0 created by losetup with the right data offset
- /mnt/recovery a mount point where i could read only! mount /dev/loop0

hope this helps others.